# Problems with segmentation of Orfeo Toolbox

Tags: qgis, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, orfeo-toolbox

[image]

I'm new to Orfeo ToolBox, and I started using the segmentation tool with an RGB orthomosaic from UAV in order to classify the different units. The result gives me a clear result with vegetation but some geometrical form after 5 hours of processing.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Is ORFEO taking too long to process? Is the segmentation fine for vegetation but poor for other classes?

Comment: yes, it takes too long but that wouldn't be the problem if it gave me a good result. It doesn't identify other classes like bare ground or rocky outcrops, I don't know how to modify the paremeters of the algorithm to get a better result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe post a screen shot of your parameters for help there.  As far as processing time, make sure your computer has enough resources to process these data.  Check your graphics card and ensure there is the correct driver. Process a single UAV image (rather than the orthomosaic) and see if that processes in a reasonable amount of time.